# Почему не выполняется SQL-запрос с PHP-переменными?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Не выполняется SQL запрос, если вместо ? задать вручную значения, то выполнится, а так нет. В чем ошибка?

```
$sql = "UPDATE info SET ? = 5 WHERE `id` = ?";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([$value, $id]);
```

Comment: Если ? = 5 это не опечатка, то см. ответ по ссылке.

Comment: @Ипатьев, да спасибо, круто расписано, но ошибка у меня оказывается в опечатке была